# Having trouble keeping search elements on one horizontal line

Tags: html, css, inline, display

I’m having trouble keeping my search fields with the search image on one line.  I have created a container area that i want centered in the middle of the screen, and I gave it a max-width of “580px” …

```
#loginArea {
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-family: 'russo_oneregular';
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 580px;
}
```

Then I created my three search elements with the magnifying glass search icon …

```
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="searchField" style="width:25%">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="searchField" style="width:25%">
    <input type="text" name="event" id="event" placeholder="Event" class="searchField">
    <input alt="Search" type="image" src="http://www.racertracks.com/assets/magnifying-glass-0220f37269f90a370c3bb60229240f2ef2a4e15b335cd42e64563ba65e4f22e4.png" class="search_button" height="40" align="middle">
```

But I can’t get everything to stay on one line even if there are 580 pixels available on the screen.  On both Mac Chrome and Firefox this looks off — https://jsfiddle.net/4sjxum1k/1/ .  Even if you expand the viewing area to have way more than 580 pixels, things are still wrapping.  I’m fine if things wrap when the screen area is small (e.g. mobile browsers), but if there is enough room, I’d like everything to display on one line.

Any help is appreciated, - Dave

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the widths of your input fields to have everything line-up on one line? Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4sjxum1k/7/

Comment: When I view that fiddle in Firefox the magnifyhing glass is wrapping to the next line, even though there are well over 580 pixels of horizontal screen real estate available.

Comment: Ok. And then when you adjust the last input field (event) to 40%, what happens?

Comment: why not use a table, perfectly acceptable and incredibly easy! https://jsfiddle.net/4sjxum1k/14/. Make it responsive, i.e use %'s as widths and it will adjust accordingly. My fiddle shows you the beginning, simply adjust the widths of the columns to suit your preferences.

Comment: A table would keep everything on one row at any screen width, but on a mobile device (e.g. 320px width), this will look really compressed and be hard to use.  At such a small screen width, I want the third input and the magnifyhing glass to spill over to another line to make things less cramped.

Comment: well that's simple to fix, just change to `display: table-row` with media queries: https://jsfiddle.net/4sjxum1k/20/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all all the input elements to "display:inline-block;" and also apply a set percentage width (width: 25%;) to each of the input elements.

```
.searchField {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-align: start;
    width:25%;
}
```

See JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/4sjxum1k/5/

Comment: You made all inputs take up 25% but there's only three inputs so things look a little cramped.  I only want the first anem and last name fields to be 25%.

Comment: Thanks but a couple of things with this -- there is a lot more space around hte magnifying glass than the width of the image (I'd like the widht of the magnifyihng glass section being the same as its actual width).  Also if there are 580 pixels available, I'd like everything to fit in one line, but here the "event" and magnifying glass search bleed over to a second line.

Answer (score 0):

Your items are too wide for your wrapping div.
You have multiple options, either increase the width of the containing box to something like 650px (for example) or reduce the width of the existing input fields.

Another idea would be to float all the form inputs to the left with a little `margin-right` value and float the submit item to the right. That would remove the default browser spacing on your elements. But adjustment to the widths are still necessary. Don't forget to add a clear fix after your `<form>`

Comment: Do you have a Fiddle that demonstrates any of this in action?